# Why isn't my car reaching it's target?

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks, path

I am making a game with car AI who is driving around the city. Here are screenshots of Navmesh, target and it's path. Why do car make so short path and doesn't reach the target?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, cast answer. It is important for me, because I must release leatest game version as soon as possible...

Comment: As your question is worded, it's a bit unclear what you're asking. May you please clarify this sentence? *Why do car make so short path and doesn't reach the target?*